# React-testing-library how get length of input value at onChange

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

i'm trying to test my form with this code. 
I wonder how i can simulate that if input value length is 10. onSubmit function will be called automatically

```
  describe('Form Component', () => {
     it('should submit when data filled length 10', async () => {
      const onSubmit = jest.fn()
      const { getByLabelText, getByTestId } = render(<Form onSubmit={onSubmit} />)
      const input = getByLabelText('input')
      await act(async () => {
        await fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: '123' } })
      })
      expect(onSubmit).toBeCalled()
     })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, this is how I would do it, using onChange event on the input and dispatching a submit event on the form (using a ref) :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Hello = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState(null);
  const [done, setDone] = useState("not submitted");

  const change = e => {
    if (e.target.value.length > 10) {
      form.dispatchEvent(new Event("submit"));
      setDone("submitted");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form
        ref={ref => {
          setForm(ref);
        }}
        onSubmit={() => console.log("submitted")}
      >
        <input label="myInput" onChange={change} />
      </form>
      {done}
    </>
  );
};
```

And the test could be something like :

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import Hello from "../hello";

test("submitted when length > 10", () => {
  const rtl = render(<Hello />);

  // no need to wrap in act, RTL does it for you
  fireEvent.change(rtl.getByLabelText("myInput"), {
    target: { value: "0000000000" }
  });

  // you should find a visual way to test that the form has been submitted, as recommends RTL
  expect(rtl.getByText("done")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/submit-form-if-length-10-ymvm4?file=/src/hello.js

Good luck !